# Google Drive SDK alternateLink With OAuth2

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I am integrating google drive files docs,spreadsheets and preasentations with my app. I need some help about alternate link.

Files.get api includes a link called "alternateLink" which opens users file with compatible editor. But when i forward user to link if user is not logged in, google shows login screen before. I am asking about how can i overcome with login screen using OAuth2 mechanizm. Should i set a cookie or smt else ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AlternateLink will always require that the user is signed-in his Google Account. If you want to use this you will have to share the document publicly which won't require sign-in then.

To use OAuth 2.0 you will have to use the 'downloadUrl' you can append the OAuth 2.0 access token to the downloadUrl like this:

```
authorizedDownloadUrl = downloadUrl + '&access_token=' + accessToken
```

Beware that the download URL expires after 24h.

Comment: I see. Actually what i want to do, providing an interface that allows users to edit their drive files without see any login page. So, as i understand, there is no way to do it with google's api. What i need to do download the file, show an editor to user to edit file then upload it back. I am not such talented to write editors for each type of file :) Do u have any suggestion to determine my way

Comment: Google Documents, Google Sheets, Google Presentations etc.. *need* users to be signed in to access non-public documents. OAuth 2 and such are only used by Google APIs, not by Google Products. The only possible way for you to avoid login would be to share the document publicly (read & write) - you can do that using the API. Then the document won't require login for edit but all editions will show as done by an anonymous user.